# Append HTML with Anchor Tags instead of Checkbox or Checkboxes Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, anchor

I am trying to get this functional example of an Append to HTML checkbox snippet to work with Anchor tags as well. Thanks!

I have been working on this for months...

Thanks for anyone who can offer a solution. I've been searching for some time.

Sincerely,
Sean Wichert, Sr. :)
512-730-1069 (Call me if you like with a solution as well, & please leave a voicemail as it's a Google Voice number I use through gmail with a headset & don't typically have it open unless I need to make a call.

```
<!-- HEAD STARTS HERE -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>        

    <!-- WORKING JAVASCRIPT FOR CHECKBOX TO HTML OUTPUT BELOW -->
    <!-- I NEED TO MAKE THIS ALSO WORK FOR ANCHOR TAGS IS THE QUESTION. -->

    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

    $(window).load(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
        var title = $(this).closest('.pdt-checkbox').find('.HTML-code-insert').html();
        var tempId = $(this).attr('id');

        // If the checkbox is checked, add the item to the ul.
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
            var html = $("<li/>", {
                title: title,
                idholder: tempId,
                text: title
            });
            $('ul.result').append(html);

        } else {

            // if the checkbox is unchecked, remove the item from the ul.
            $('[idholder="' + tempId + '"]', 'ul').remove();        
        }
    });
    });//]]>  

    $.fn.selectText = function () {
        return $(this).each(function (index, el) {
            if (document.selection) {
                var range = document.body.createTextRange();
                range.moveToElementText(el);
                range.select();
            } else if (window.getSelection) {
                var range = document.createRange();
                range.selectNode(el);
                window.getSelection().addRange(range);
            }
        });
    }

    </script>       

<!-- BODY STARTS HERE -->

<!-- WORKING CHECKBOX SAMPLE BELOW -->

<div class="pdt-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="pc-repair-step-one" value="Yes" /><label for="pc-repair-step-one">
1. SMWN</label><div style="display:none;" title="#" class="HTML-code-insert">SMWN</div></div>

<!-- NOT WORKING ANCHOR ATTEMPT BELOW -->

<li class="addmenui"><a class="anchor" onclick="javascript:pcSecurityRepair();" href="#" id="pcsecrepair" value="Yes">PC Security Repair</a><label for="pcsecrepair"></label><div title="#" style="display:none;" class="HTML-code-insert">SMWN</div></li>

<div onclick="$(this).selectText()" style="background:url(button.jpg) 0 0 no repeat"; class="ctrl-a" alt="Click me to select the Notes.">           

<ul style="
font-size: 0px;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding: 20px;
font-family: Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;                                    font-weight: 700;                                           line-height: 24px;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #999959;
" class="result">
</ul>       
</div>
```

Comment: _"to work with Anchor tags as well."_ - What does that mean? The existing code has some "If the checkbox is checked" logic, so how does that translate to anchor tags?

Comment: are the anchor tags adding content to the ul as well?

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

you should use some class toggle instead of value attribute

```
$('a.anchor').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');

        var title = $(this).parent().find('.HTML-code-insert').html();
        var tempId = $(this).attr('id');

        // If the anchor is clicked, add the item to the ul.
        if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')){
            var html = $("<li/>", {
                title: title,
                idholder: tempId,
                text: title
            });
            $('ul.result').append(html);

        } else {

            // if the anchor is not clicked, remove the item from the ul.
            $('[idholder="' + tempId + '"]', 'ul').remove();        
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try something along these lines...

```
//content to be inserted
var listItem1 = $('<li>').text('My List Item 1').attr('id', 'listItem1');
var listItem2 = $('<li>').text('My List Item 2').attr('id', 'listItem2');

//reference to target ul
var targetUL = $('#result'); // reference to the result <ul>

//click event for checkbox
$("#pc-repair-step-one").on('click', function () {
    if (this.checked) targetUL.append(listItem1); //checkbox is checked add the item
    else $('#listItem1').remove(); // checkbox is not checked remove the item
});

//click event for anchor
$('#pc-repair-step-two').on('click', function () {
    var listItem = $('#listItem2'); // reference to listItem
    if(listItem.length === 1) listItem.remove(); //item exits remove it
    else targetUL.append(listItem2); // item doesnt exist add it
});
```

what im doing there is checking for either the state of the checkbox or the existence of the inserted element in the case of the links... and appending or removing it from the

here is a fiddle with this idea working... hope this helps you on you way
http://jsfiddle.net/pixelchemist/LL5QU/